# How to make progress bar works while web browser navigating?

Tags: c#

I'm working with progress bar and web browser control on C# but I have no idea to make a smooth progress bar while it navigating, do you have step by step to create it, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean a progress bar or a generic animation? Maybe an hourglass cursor while it is loading?

Comment: no i mean really a progress bar, so i know the progress for loading a web page.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`WebBrowser.ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged) Event:

```
private void WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, 
                                         WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Maximum = (int) e.MaximumProgress;
    progressBar.Value = (int) e.CurrentProgress;
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't handle the case where webbrowser returns out of range values

Answer (score 3):

A progress bar is only useful if you know *before* the action how much you are going to do. For loading a web page this would mean knowing the size of every resource that is going to be loaded. That's not really feasible. There are also other parts that cannot really be predicted:

1. DNS lookup
2. Opening a connection to the server
3. Resources loaded from other resources, e.g. a JavaScript embedding another CSS or CSS referencing images
4. ...

All major browsers have long since given up trying to show *progress* for loading a page; now they merely show loading activity instead.

The WebBrowser control has a [`ProgressChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged) but I don't know how reliable it is. But it's probably your best try. All the points mentioned above still apply, though. Neither you nor the browser know enough to make the progress bar accurate so it either is a rough approximation (starting after loading the HTML and representing just the loaded additional resources) or it jerks around or even run backwards when the estimate of total resources was wrong.

Comment: Yes maybe, but do you know how to implement progress changed events on web browser?

Comment: that's not entirely true. my browser shows a progress bar. i believe it appears after the headers are received though; probably if `Content-Length` is present.

Comment: Actually I've implemented background worker control to monitor the progress of the browser, but it still can't get the whole process. E.g i clicked a link on a web then the progress bar doesn't take any effect because i can't implement it on progress changed event.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    if ((e.CurrentProgress > 0) && (e.CurrentProgress < 100))
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong! e.CurrentProgress should be compared with e.MaximumProgress which in my case is always greater than 100.