# Progress Bar working on WebBrowser generated in code C#

Tags: c#, browser, progress-bar, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm programming a WebBrowser in C# and I have the following problem:
When a button is clicked a new tabPage is generated in tabControl1 with the WebBrowser.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.Url = new System.Uri("http://google.com");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Aba "+ (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString()));
        tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabCount - 1].Controls.Add(browser);

    }
```

I need to know how to make the progress bar work with the webbrowser that belongs to the current active tabPage.
How and where do I insert the following code:

```
toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int) e.MaximumProgress;
toolStripProgressBar1.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
```

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814523/how-to-make-progress-bar-works-while-web-browser-navigating

Comment: i'm not using a fixed webBrowser like in the link you sent. In my program, the WebBrowser is generated in code. If i write the code in webBrowser1.ProgressChanged it will work only in webBrowser1 and the other tabs will not interact with the progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Anonymous Function:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
browser.Url = new System.Uri("http://google.com");
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Aba " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString()));
tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabCount - 1].Controls.Add(browser);
browser.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler( delegate (object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs events)
    {
        if ((int)events.CurrentProgress > 0)
        {
            toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int)events.MaximumProgress;
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = (int)events.CurrentProgress;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with crushing cause the progressbar was all ready full, so here's this problem solved.

```
    private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)e.CurrentProgress > 0)
        {
            ProgressBar.Maximum = (int)e.MaximumProgress;
            if (ProgressBar.Maximum == (int)e.MaximumProgress)
                ProgressBar.Value = 0;
            ProgressBar.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: not really, just if someone gets the same error as i did... :d